# What is going on behind this numpy selection behavior?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

Answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45425527/how-do-i-select-a-row-from-a-complex-numpy-array/45425986#45425986), some others and I were actually wrong by considering that the following would work:

Say one has

```
test = [ [ [0], 1 ],
         [ [1], 1 ]
       ]
import numpy as np
nptest = np.array(test)
```

What is the reason behind

```
>>> nptest[:,0]==[1]
array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

while one has

```
>>> nptest[0,0]==[1],nptest[1,0]==[1]
(False, True)
```

---

or

```
>>> nptest==[1]
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

or

```
>>> nptest==1
array([[False,  True],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Is it the *degeneracy* in term of dimensions which causes this.

Comment: This is not a kind of interaction anyone cared to make easy when designing NumPy. NumPy is designed for rigid multidimensional grids of numbers. Trying to get anything but a rigid multidimensional grid is going to be painful.

Comment: Moral of the story: Don't use `dtype=object` arrays. They are stunted Python lists, with worse performance characteristics, and `numpy` is not designed to handle the case of sequence-like containers within these object arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nptest` is a 2D array of object dtype, and the first element of each row is a list.

`nptest[:, 0]` is a 1D array of object dtype, each of whose elements are lists.

When you do `nptest[:,0]==[1]`, NumPy does not perform an elementwise comparison of each element of `nptest[:,0]` against the list `[1]`. It creates as high-dimensional an array as it can from `[1]`, producing the 1D array `np.array([1])`, and then [broadcasts](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) the comparison, comparing each element of `nptest[:,0]` against the integer 1.

Since no list in `nptest[:, 0]` is equal to 1, all elements of the result are False.